# Is inverse of expectation smaller? $E\left(\frac{1}{Y}\right) \ge \frac{1}{E(Y)}$

Tags: random-variables, expectation

If Y is a positive r.v. with finite expectation, then is the following true?

$$E\left(\frac{1}{Y}\right) > \frac{1}{E(Y)}$$

Comment: Yes, this follows by Jensen's inequality: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality

Answer (score 2):

By Cauchy-Schwartz We have $$1=\int_\Omega d\mu = \int_\Omega \frac{1}{\sqrt{Y}}\sqrt{Y}d\mu  \le \int_\Omega Yd\mu  \int_\Omega \frac{1}{Y}d\mu  = E(Y)E(\frac1Y)$$
That is
$$E\left(\frac{1}{Y}\right) \ge \frac{1}{E(Y)}$$